# How to force authentication with Passport

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

I have implemented 2 routes:
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate....);
app.get('/admin', myfunction);

If the user first posts to login, I have got him redirected to /admin.

What if the user goes straight to get /admin? How do I ensure that unless he is logged in, he is not allowed to access /admin and is redirected to the login screen?

Also for APIs that are accessed from the application, how do I send 401 if the user is not authenticated by passport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Passport is middleware that needs to be included where you need route protection**

Passport.js is middleware for Express.  You include it on any routes that need to be protected, not just on the login route/page.

As a refresher, the approved answer to [What does middleware and app.use actually mean in Expressjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337572/what-does-middleware-and-app-use-actually-mean-in-expressjs) and this link to the off-site page [A short guide to Connect Middleware](http://stephensugden.com/middleware_guide/) can also help.

**Protecting an API route**

First, to repeate what was said above...Passport is middleware so you need to include it on the routes defining the API.  Additionally, see:

- [how can I protect an api endpoint with passportjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000195/how-can-i-protect-an-api-endpoint-with-passportjs)
- [passportjs RESTful auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572600/passport-js-restful-auth)

As for the 401, Passport will generate these for you upon failure if you haven't written your own handler for these.